# Always require a plugin to be loaded

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I am writing an application with RequireJS and Knockout JS. The application includes an extension to knockout that adds `ko.protectedObservable` to the main knockout object. I would like this to always be available on the require'd knockout object, and not only when I specify it in the dependencies. I could concat the files together, but that seems that it should be unnecessary.

Additionally, I can put `knockout-protectedObservable` as a dependency for `knockout` in the requirejs shim configuration, but that just leads to a circular dependency and it all fails to load.

Edit:
I've solved me issue, but seems hacky, is there a better way?

-- Main.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['knockout'], function(ko) {
        require(['knockout-protectedObservable']);
    });
</script>
```

-- knockout-protectedObservable.js

```
define(['knockout'], function(ko) {
    ko.protectedObservable = { ... };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the simpler way is to make your `knockout` ID point at the updated `ko`:

```
require.config = {
  // Your other settings
  "paths": {
    "knockout": "wrappers/enhanced-knockout",
    "vendor/knockout": "third-party/knockout.3-2.min"
  }
}
```

Then your `enhanced-knockout` script adds what it needs to `vendor/knockout`:

```
define(['vendor/knockout'], function(ko) {
    ko.protectedObservable = { ... };
    return ko;
});
```